# Testing JS callback with timeout using Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I need to test some code in Angular with Jasmine, but the thing is that I can't do this because of $timeout call. So the code looks like this:

```
$scope.add = function() {
    SomeService.add(id, function() {
        $timeout(function() {
            $scope.showSuccessMessage();
        }, 1000)
    }, function() {})
};
```

So the test code is:

```
describe('method add', function() {
    it('should add', function() {
        spyOn(SomeService, 'add').and.callFake(function(id, successCallback, errorCallback) {
            spyOn(scope, 'showSuccessMessage');
            successCallback();
            expect(scope.showSuccessMessage).toHaveBeenCalled();
        });
        scope.add();
        expect(SomeService.add).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

And the problem is that because of the timeout call I can't check that `showSuccessMessage()` has been called. I know about Jasmine's ability to work with timeouts but in that case I can't find a working way because of calling it in the callback.

Comment: you could put expect under `setTimeout`, it works for me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [**`flush`**](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$timeout#flush) your timeout by using `$timeout.flush()` after calling the original function. That should allow you to access the `successCallback`.

Also, I would put the `spy` and `expect` of the `showSuccessMessage` outside the other `spy`

```
describe('method add', function() {
    it('should add', function() {
        spyOn(SomeService, 'add').and.callFake(function(id, successCallback, errorCallback) {
            successCallback();
        });
        spyOn(scope, 'showSuccessMessage');
        scope.add();
        $timeout.flush();
        expect(SomeService.add).toHaveBeenCalled();
        expect(scope.showSuccessMessage).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Im not very familiar with the workings of angular, I hope this helps:

You can use the done function for asynchronous code:

```
    it('should add', function (done) {
        $scope.successCallback = function () {
            // successCallback was called
            done();
        }

        $scope.add();
    });
```

Comment: AngularJS ngMock module was designed to provide synchronous tests in Jasmine. `done` is never needed for testing purely Angular code.